# Return value to class object in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a header file:

```
using namespace std;

class IntList{
private:
    int *Intl;
    int Capacity;
    int Count;
public:
    IntList(int capacity){
        Capacity = capacity;
        Count = 0;
        Intl = new int[capacity];
    }

    ~IntList(){
        delete Intl;
    }

    //adds the integers of the specified collection to the end of the List; return false if the new Count will be greater than Capacity
    bool AddRange(const IntList &items){
        //int *Temp = items.;
        if(items.Count > Capacity - Count){
            return false;
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i <items.Count; i++){
                Intl[Count] = items.Intl[i];
                Count++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

But I don't know why I can't return value to IntList object in there:

```
//creates a copy of a range of elements in the source List
        IntList GetRange(int index, int count){
            IntList A(count);
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                A.Intl[i] = Intl[index -1 +i];
            }   
            return A;
        }
```

I want to return value of `A` whose type is `IntList` but I meet an error on `"_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` in visual studio 2010. How can I repair it?

Comment: *I have a header file: `using namespace std;`* You should never add using directives in your header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an object which is returned by value makes a call to `copy-constructor .` You must make a copy-constructor and define it so that you get appropriate results. Returning by reference actually does not require call to copy constructor but should not be made for a temporary object. Also since you have a pointer type as member variable in class . It would be appropiate for you to overload the `=` operator. It should be define properly to avoid `memory leak`. Do something like this `Intlist a=GetRange(index,count)` . Also you should create a copy constructor for this . Your code also has a bug that it doesnot overload`=` operator for class Intlist .

you can write a copy constructor something like this :-

```
   Intlist::Intlist(const Intlist& cSource)
   {         
     capacity = cSource.capacity; 
     count=  cSource.count;
    // Intl is a pointer, so we need to deep copy it if it is non-null
    if (cSource.Intl)
     {
       // allocate memory for our copy
      Intl = new int[capacity];

    // Copy the Intl into our newly allocated memory in for loop
     for(i=0;i<capacity;i++)
     {
       // copy part
      }
    }
    else
    intl = NULL;
  }
```

Just an e.g how you should write it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore  did not exactly meant to return temporary object by reference . I just wanted to let him know that in that case call to copy constructor would not be made

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Modified it . Thanks for Suggestion :)

Comment: I try anh fix it but it doesn't return value?

Comment: @user1366448 Did you write a copy constructor for it . If so can you post that code . Also post the code in Which you are calling GetRange function .

Comment: // Copy contructor
 IntList (IntList &range){  
  Intl = new int;
  *Intl = *range.Intl;
  cout<<"copy complete\n\n";
 }

Answer (score 3):

Because `int *Intl;` is an object you manually manage, you'll need to implement the copy constructor for your class.

The function `GetRange` returns by value. The local object `A` gets destroyed, and its member `Intl` gets deleted in the destructor, so your copy (as copied by the default copy constructor) is only a shallow one, and will contain an invalid member.

EDIT: As Rob correctly pointed out, you'll also need to implement the assignment operator (you already have a destructor).

Comment: See also [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three.